# Google 414 Error with Youtube API requests

Tags: youtube-api

my company has been developing a TV Guide web app for Youtube for the past 3 months and we launched our beta yesterday, http://martelltv.com/

It works fairly well as intended, but with one problem: we're getting a Google 414 error under certain circumstances.

To create the effect of broadcast television using Youtube, the episode containers  “play back to back” feature currently works with a playlist that is consumed in the Youtube servers. We store the YT video ids and when someone ask to watch an episode we send the ids to the YT API and YT get back to us with the videos. However, we've noticed that if we schedule more than (I think the number was?) 50 videos to play in a 'day', we get a Google 414 error.

We believe the 414 error is mostly happening because of the YT restrictions, and would like to know if that restriction could be increased for our app so a full 24 hour worth of videos could be scheduled in a Station for playing?

Answer (score 0):

An [HTTP 414 response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15) indicates that the request URI is too long. I don't know how you're constructing the URIs that you're sending to the YouTube API (whether you're using a client library, constructing them manually, etc.), but I'd recommend you take a specific look at the full URI that you're requesting when you get back a 414 response and see if there's any "junk" or extraneous characters that you're adding to it that would cause it to trigger that error.